# Ignoring case while searching in pandas

Tags: pandas

I can list the details of rows having the name "Flipkart" as follows

```
fund_data[fund_data['StartupName'] == "Flipkart"]
```

but how to do it if the name has case variations like "flipkart","FlipKart",etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simpliest is convert to [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and compare by lower-case `string`:

```
fund_data[fund_data['StartupName'].str.lower() == "flipkart"]
```